# Mail::later() sends immediately in laravel

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.1 for my project and when I use `Mail::later(3600, ...);`, it sends the email immediately, this should be after 1hr. Why it is not after 1hr sending?

Queue Driver: sync

Comment: Do you have queues set up? What is your queue driver? Show some code, you do not need to share the complex math of time conversion.

Comment: @Kyslik Check the update.

Comment: As I thought `sync` driver means no matter what delay you want 1 hour or 5 seconds its gonna fire right in the same request cycle.

Answer (score 7):

Just check queue settings. 
Be sure for these options:

change queue drive to`QUEUE_DRIVER=database` in `.env` file

create jobs table with this command `php artisan queue:table`

add `implements ShouldQueue` to the mail class.

after that you can try with `php artisan queue:work` command.

Comment: Great. I'll try it.